# Bat File for install of programs - make one install wait till the install is finished

Tags: file, batch-file

I am very new to .bat files.  I am making a bat file to install all the programs we need at our company.  One issue I am running into - I worked with Microsoft to create an msi file to install Office 365 however I would like this the line where it is installing Office 365 to wait till the install is finished before it moves onto the next line in the bat file.  What should I be typing for that.  Below is the first part of the bat file and you can see that the 2nd to last line is where I am installing office.  This sometimes works and sometimes does not.

Any help please?

```
%windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

"\\nas\install\IBM\Client Access\VR7_1\Windows\image64a\setup.exe" /s /v"/qn /norestart ADDLOCAL=afp,scs,req,inavbo,dt,dtexcel,odbc,emu"

msiexec /i "\\nas\install\ADOBE\Adobe STD X USE\Setup\AcroStan.msi" TRANSFORMS=AcroStan.mst /qb

msiexec /i "\\nas\install\MICROSOFT\Office 365 ProPlus\NewInstallMSI\OfficeProPlus64Bit.msi" /qb

Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:"\\nas\install\MICROSOFT\Windows 10\Win10ENT\sources\sxs" /LimitAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `start "" /wait` is your best option here. I do not have all your commands, so you would need to test this:

```
start "" /wait "%windir%\System32\reg.exe" ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

start "" /wait "\\nas\install\IBM\Client Access\VR7_1\Windows\image64a\setup.exe" /s /v"/qn /norestart ADDLOCAL=afp,scs,req,inavbo,dt,dtexcel,odbc,emu"

start "" /wait "msiexec" /i "\\nas\install\ADOBE\Adobe STD X USE\Setup\AcroStan.msi" TRANSFORMS=AcroStan.mst /qb

start "" /wait "msiexec" /i "\\nas\install\MICROSOFT\Office 365 ProPlus\NewInstallMSI\OfficeProPlus64Bit.msi" /qb

start "" /wait "Dism" /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:"\\nas\install\MICROSOFT\Windows 10\Win10ENT\sources\sxs" /LimitAccess
```